# Is Linux Mint supporting AMD graphic cards?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, drivers, distributions, amd

I want to upgrade to a new distro because Ubuntu 16.04LTS has MAJOR problems with any graphical use, I can't edit videos, and the screen is really glitchy, I can't watch videos on fullscreen because of this anoying glitchy thing. I would be also happy if someone would suggest a distro. I heard that Ubuntu 14.04 supports AMD graphics. So what should I get?

Comment: Relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-and-amd-graphics

Comment: This question is meaningless: hardware support depends essentially on when the distribution was assembled, and not what distribution it is. There may be known issues with your graphics card model, but since you didn't bother to tell us what it is, we can't help you with that.

Comment: @edwinksl:  That looks like a very appropriate answer.  I would suggest you adapt it and post it as a direct answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of Mint is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so you're not going to have much luck there. I believe most, if not all, current versions of Linux are incompatible with `fglrx` (as long as they use Xorg 1.18 or later).

If you want to be sure you can use your card to its full potential, you'll have to find a distro you like that uses a version of Xorg below 1.18. Ubuntu 14.04 will work, and so will any distro based on it.

If you want a more complete explanation and some other options for AMD, look at the link edwinksl provided. I really don't want to rewrite what I wrote there, so you'll have to go look ;).

https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-16-04-and-amd-graphics

Comment: “all current versions of Linux are incompatible with AMD” ??? What on earth are you talking about? The lack of the horribly buggy proprietary driver doesn't make it impossible to use AMD graphics cards. Maybe some very recent models that the free driver doesn't support yet.

Comment: @Gilles sorry, I meant incompatible with proprietary drivers. I'll revise it to be a bit less absolute.